# Grouping dataset by dates and converting columns into categories

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerquery

I have a powerquery-table with data structured as picture 1, with 1 row per date, and capacity input per vendor separated into columns. This is creating some issues in creating pivot-tables, as i cannot simply filter which vendor i want to look at by a single column.

I think the solution would be to structure the data as shown in picture 2, but is there a way to change from one format to the other? In other situations i need the data structured as is. So ideally i need a way to present the same dataset in either format as needed.

Current table:

[image: Current table]

Preferable table:

[image: Preferable table]

Comment: After loading it to PQ editor, select the first column, right click and unpivot other columns, you shall see the desired output!

Comment: That is the solution

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya so simple!! Thank you! I've been wondering for a while, but did not have the google-skills to help me.

Comment: @Morten try to search on SO, also follow @horseyride's solutions on `PQ` you shall learn as well!